# Sql variable on select query

Tags: mysql

hey lets say we have 3 tables tbl1,tbl2,tbl3 and using the below query you can view the data

```
    select * from tbl1
    select * from tbl2
    select * from tbl3
```

my question is that can you eliminate repetition by using variables? like for example

```
    DECLARE @x as varchar(60)
    set @x = tbl1
    set @x = tbl2
    set @x = tbl3
    select * from @x
    Go
```

I hate retyping the exact query does anyone know a way to make the query work I think it would save me loads of time. thanks

Comment: You need to clear the question...

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a [`stored procedure`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) for that?

*Example:*

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `selectAllTables`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `selectAllTables`()
BEGIN
SELECT * from tbl1;
SELECT * from tbl2;
SELECT * from tbl3;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

*Usage:*

```
CALL `selectAllTables`();
```

Comment: I have never used a stored procedure before so I cant really understand whats happening there , lemme research about these stored procedures and will get back to you thanx

Answer (score 1):

If you meant [Dynamic SQL (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) type of support in MySQL, you may achieve this using prepare statement in stored procedure

First [create a stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) with a parameter to take table name in string:

```
DELIMITER ///

CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllRecords(__TABLE__NAME varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', __TABLE__NAME);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END///

DELIMITER ;
```

Next, you may [CALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html) the stored procedure sending in the table name:

```
call SelectAllRecords('table1')
call SelectAllRecords('table2')
call SelectAllRecords('table3')
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your Question right then the below Query will work for you.

```
DECLARE @x as table
set @x = select * from tbl3
select * from @x
Go
```